# How to handle Day light saving in Ajax calendar control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, calendar, ajaxcontroltoolkit

How do I handle the Day Light Savnigs in ASP.net Ajax calendar control. I want to off it. I dont want the calendar control to show a different date.

Issue -
When I select 19-Oct-2014 in the calendar  the Ajax calendar shows 18-oct-2014 due to the DST. How to ignore the DST.

Help is appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm guessing this is related to your time zone, as daylight savings is only an hour difference. Is your local time close to the prime meridian? Can you try setting a different time zone when setting the value of the calendar?

Comment: when I click on 19th october, the calendar shows 18th oct after the post back in my web page. this is happening where the user is in DST time zone